# How add a text like test in First Of File Name with Batchfile

Tags: batch-file, filenames

How add a text like test in FirstOfFile Name with Batchfile

I have some PDF file in a directory. How i can add text "Test" to First Of File Name

My file is like

1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf

I want have when Run

test1.pdf
test2.pdf
test3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following samples? When you use these samples, at first, please set `set add=test`

#### Pattern 1

If there are only PDF files in the directory with PDF files, you can use following batch file. But when you use this, please put this batch file to outside of the PDF directory. When there is this file in the same directory to PDF directory, this batch file is also renamed.

```
@echo off
set add=test
for %%a in (*) do ren %%a %add%%%a
```

#### Pattern 2

If there are PDF files and other files in the directory with PDF files, you can use following batch file. In this case, the batch file and other files are not renamed. Only PDF files are renamed.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set add=test
set i=0
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
  set ar[!i!]=%%a
  set /a i=!i!+1
)
set /a i=!i!-1
for /l %%e in (0,1,!i!) do (
  ren !ar[%%e]! %add%!ar[%%e]!
)
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.